# iPhone is not available

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode11

I have an issue with trying to run the app on iOS 12.4.7 where I'm always getting this message in Xcode:

> iPhone is not available. Please reconnect the device

I have checked many answers related to this issue and in most cases issue is connected to Xcode version and iOS 13. In another words lower Xcode version then it should be. I have tried many things: re-connecting, restarting Xcode, restarting iPhone.

My Xcode version is 11.5 and deployment is set to iOS 12.0 but still I can not run the app on iOS 12.4.7 which is the version of iOS on my phone. I think Xcode 11.5 should support running the app on lower versions than iOS 13. Also I have enough free storage on iPhone to run the app.

On simulator, iOS 13+, app will run but on real phone it doesn't. Unfortunately I can not upgrade my iOS version and I need to test in app purchases. Any help is more than welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I think Xcode 11.5 should support running the app on lower versions than iOS 13." Stop thinking that. — What model is the phone, by the way?

Comment: @matt I have iPhone 6 and unable to upgrade to iOS 13

Comment: Yes, I thought that's what you'd say. And that's the problem. The issue isn't the system version, it's the device type. Xcode 11.5 just isn't going to support running on your device. You can run the _app_ on your device, no problem; but not _from Xcode_.

Comment: @matt rest in peace debugging apps on iPhone 6.

Comment: Well you have much bigger fish to fry. What's your plan for when you can no longer submit an app without using Xcode 12?

Comment: @matt I still have 2 kidneys - just kidding. But it is interesting: when device becomes let say deprecated for debugging iOS apps? Documentation says: The Xcode 11.5 release supports on-device debugging for iOS 8 and later, but I couldn't run the app from Xcode on my iPhone 6.  Or maybe this is suitable for asking new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't the system version, it's the device type (iPhone 6). Xcode 11.5 just isn't going to support running on your device. You can run the *app* on your device, no problem; but not *from Xcode*.